# Http vs. Https in Stress Testing

Tags: https, http

Does anyone know if using http vs. https in [a stress test like this](https://stressgrid.com/blog/benchmarking_go_vs_node_vs_elixir/) would likely yield a huge difference?

I'd personally be inclined to use https rather than http as that's more likely what my application's users are using to connect, but wasn't sure if https would introduce variation making it difficult to parse the results of the test on a specific variable like language/framework

Comment: My very limited experience is that TLS impact on performance is based more on how many key exchanges are being performed. If it's a few connections all being cached (I think not the technically correct TLS term), it's hardly any impact on anything. If it's 100% fresh connections doing key exchange, it can make a very real difference.

Comment: Is a real difference on the order of ms? Smaller? Larger?